# rails 4.0.0 destroy nested attributes throws error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models Question and Answer. Question has many Answers. Creating and Updating of nested attributes are working. But when a nested attribute is set to remove by setting '_destroy' to '1' or 'true'. App throws error.

In controller params are permitted as

```
params.require(:question).permit(:name, :answers_attributes => [:id, :name,  :_destroy ])
```

error as

```
Undefined method 'name' on nil class
```

Comment: What error does it throw?

Comment: Where is the error being raised? Actual code of that line, and surrounding lines, would be helpful